# EMPTY OBJECT instead of a MESH

Tags: animation, mesh, objects

I'm working on a blender project made by other guys and I've noticed that instead of normal meshes I've got a lot of empty objects. In the outliner panel every empty object is shown as it was a normal mesh (as to say: it contains armatures, modifiers, animations) but in the 3D view there's just an arrow and when I render nothing shows up.

Hope that makes sense,
Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP8ac.jpg)

Comment: if the vertices/edges/faces count is not zero, the data should be there, maybe hidden (check the outliner "eye" icon)... otherwise, share the file for others to check, if possible, or show some screenshot to grasp some info and give hints...

Comment: I've just add a screenshot, hoping that it could help you understand the problem!

Comment: that object is an "empty" (plain axes), not a mesh... mesh object have another icon in the outliner... like various "cube" objects above that

Comment: Yes, I know. But I'm wondering if those empties weren't meshes THEN converted to empties (plain axes). As you can see in the outliner panel, the empty "a.lapin.Clone" contains an Armature, some modifiers and some vertex group. Why?

Comment: ok, sorry, I didn't see you already wrote that. I also see that your Blender version is quite old... you could try with a newer one, to open it, it could be that who gave you the file had a newer version that yours, maybe.

Comment: The mesh you have, which is called "a.lapin.Clone1" is parented to an empty which you see in the viewport. This is done often to make animation process easier as one has to create animations for the empty and the mesh will follow it. the fact that the mesh isn't seen is another question, probably this is due to animation. Did you try to play the animation (`Alt`+`A`) ? What are the keyframes in the dopesheet ?

Answer (score 1):

Your objects are in other **[layers](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/layers.html)** than the active layer.

Prsss the <kbd>`</kbd> (grave, or back tick) [image]  Key to make all layers visible.

[image]

[image]

If the objects are not rendering either check your [render layers](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/layers.html)